# jQuery file upload plugin: file name / catch the file PHP side

Tags: php, jquery, file

I am using the BlueImp jQuery-file-upload to upload images to server. The code:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'upload.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    disableImageResize: false,
    imageMaxWidth: 600,
    imageMaxHeight: 500,
    imageCrop: false // Force cropped images
})
```

How do I catch the file in upload.php? `move_uploaded_file(??????????????,'bla.jpg');`

Comment: a var_dump($_FILES) should be point you the way

Comment: Ok and how could I save the var_dump to a file and read it then? I guess the file name will never be the same, generated by the plugin, can I just declare the file name in the jQuery code? Or catch the file PHP side no matter what the name is?

Comment: look at this files https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tree/master/server/php you can config the upload folder and the lib  can do the job for you

Comment: This file is 56kb full of non necessary settings I just want to catch the file raw for further processing

Answer (score 0):

That's how I solved that:

Change the form

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```

to

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="bla">
```

And inside upload.php

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bla']['tmp_name'],'bla.jpg');
```